# Limiting woocommerce cart to one item from one specific category but allow unlimited items from other categories

Tags: woocommerce, limit, product-quantity

I found this code that restricts user's purchase to one per category for the categories of your choice. 
So currently the user could purchase 1 item from cat a. 
The problem is that I would like this item removed if the customer changes mind and adds a different 
item from cat a.

The $max_num_products ), 'error' ); prevents the new product from being added and the old product removed.
(no wc_add_notice is required) since the customer is choosing "delivery" or "Pickup"

I added WC()->cart->empty_cart(); // this empties the entire cart and adds new selection... not what I need.

Any help very much appreciated.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'allowed_quantity_per_category_in_the_cart', 10, 2 );function allowed_quantity_per_category_in_the_cart( $passed, $product_id) {

$max_num_products = 1;// change the maximum allowed in the cart
$running_qty = 0;

$restricted_product_cats = array();

//Restrict particular category/categories by category slug
$restricted_product_cats[] = 'cat-a';


// Getting the current product category slugs in an array
$product_cats_object = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach($product_cats_object as $obj_prod_cat) $current_product_cats[]=$obj_prod_cat->slug;


// Iterating through each cart item
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key=>$cart_item ){

    // Restrict $max_num_products from each category
    if( has_term( $current_product_cats, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )) {

        // count(selected category) quantity
        $running_qty += (int) $cart_item['quantity'];

        // More than allowed products in the cart is not allowed
        if( $running_qty >= $max_num_products ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Only %s '.($max_num_products>1?'products from this category are':'product from this category is').' allowed in the cart.',  $max_num_products ), 'error' );

        //$passed = WC()->cart->empty_cart(); // this empties the entire cart and adds new selection... not what I need
          $passed = false; // don't add the new product to the cart
            // We stop the loop
            break;
        }

    }
}
return $passed;}
```